# Lightswitch Extension Library Control for HTML

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I want to create custom reusable Content Type for Lightswitch HTML.

I followed couple of tutorials on creating Control in Lightswitch Extension Library including one on msdn, but as I understand it's only applicable for Silverlight. Am I right to assume that?

How can same thing be achieved for Lightswitch HTML? I know Wijimo and couple of other guys are doing the same thing, but I can't find any information for this topic.

PLEASE HELP!